# Why doesn't the SE iOS app allow complex formatting tools?

Tags: feature-request

There is this feature in the desktop version, or safari version, of  Puzzling SE that hides a section of the question or answer until  the mouse moves over it. In the SE app, it is called "spoilers". When a person is creating a question in SE app, he cannot include spoilers. This is a bit of a disadvantage.

My question is that why doesn't the SE app include spoilers. I would like users to be able to include spoilers in questions they create via a mobile device.

Comment: Everywhere, on the mobile app or on the desktop site, you can do spoilers like this: `>! `.

Comment: Yet it does not work on the mobile app, I don't mean site, I mean app.

Comment: Are you using the iOS app? It's working for me.

Comment: Do you mean it is not showing correctly on the right side of the screen? For example, if you type `>! Hello`, does it show `! Hello`? It will show correctly when you submit the question and on the final preview (press the yellow box on the top right).

Comment: I think that this question belongs to MetaSE rather than PuzzlingMeta

Comment: @mmking Thank you for solving my question!

Comment: Perhaps this should be tagged [status-bydesign]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does. Everywhere, you can do spoilers by using `>!`.

The preview shown on the right when you are typing doesn't show spoilers correctly. For example, if you type `>! Hello`, you see `! Hello`:

[image: preview while typing]

When you submit the question or see the final preview by pressing the yellow box on the top right that says "Tap here to see the final preview", it will show correctly:

[image: final preview]